# 'Invoke-Webrequest' works fine on prompt but fails when executed through

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-agent, invoke-webrequest

I am reading latest code from github to update the procs.  It works well when I execute from powershell.  But it fails when I do from SQL Server Agent Job. This is the format of my code

`cd "C:\Folder\" [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol ='Ssl3, Tls, tls12'  Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repository/folder/file.sql -Headers @{"Authorization"="token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Accept"= "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"} -OutFile ./file.sql`

ExecutionPolicy is set Unrestricted
I am using SQL Server 2012 sp4 (KB4018073) on Windows 2012 R2.

It was working few weeks back and I suspect that it started failing only after Wndows Security updates.
These are the updates installed recently:
Security Update for Windows (KB5023790)
Security Update for Windows (KB5025288)
Security Update for Windows (KB5023764)
Security Update for Windows (KB5026415)
Security Update for Windows (KB5026409)
Security Update for Windows (KB5026366)
Update for Windows (KB3191564)
Update for Windows (KB3031044)
Update for Windows (KB5023822)

Any clues? guidelines?

I even tried executing it using cmdExec type (calling powershell.exe).  It is not working.  I am not getting any specifc error.
I tried with Sql using xp_cmdshell and it is also failing.

But it is working when I executed from powershell or command prompt .

Comment: Add some logging statements to see what the script does during runtime. Also see if there's anyting relevant in the Agent's job history.

Comment: Only TLS12 and TLS13 are valid.  Updates may of changed the certificate to TLS13 and now the code is failing.

Comment: What was the error message? And why are you setting `SecurityProtocol` manually? Side note: you don't need to use the `cmdexec` subsystem, you can set `powershell` directly

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
I am not getting any error message, but the unable to download the file. When I executed the same codemanually using powershell_ise it works.  It fails only on sql agent job.
Thank you @jdweng TLS13 is the issue.  I changed it and now it is working

Comment: TLS 1.3 is not supported on 2012-r2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/874023/tls1-3-on-windows-2012-r2).  Only way is to use a library like OpenSSL to perform TLS.